# Traceback on OpenCV Hough Circles

Tags: python, opencv

2nd post here (I Think)
I got an
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\bala006\OneDrive - St John's Anglican College\Desktop\Personal\Torch\lick.py", line 30, in 
circles = cv.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:2253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'

error. Hopefully everything is in order... Thanks.
I created a cascade using Cascade Trainer and am using it to detect Ping Pong balls.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np 

camera = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW)

cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')



while(1):
    _,img = camera.read()
    img = cv.flip(img,1)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector()

    LowerRegion = np.array([4,142,149],np.uint8)
    upperRegion = np.array([33,255,255],np.uint8)

    redObject = cv.inRange(hsv,LowerRegion,upperRegion)

    kernal = np.ones((1,1),"uint8")

    red = cv.morphologyEx(redObject,cv.MORPH_OPEN,kernal)
    red = cv.dilate(red,kernal,iterations=1)

    res1=cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = red)
    
    circles = cv.HoughCircles(img, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)



    cv.imshow("Masking ",res1)
    cv.imshow("please work", img)

    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        camera.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

`HoughCircles` does not support colored image.

You need to convert `img` to Grayscale before executing `HoughCircles`:

```
gray_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray_frame, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
```

The exception message includes a C++ statement that raises by OpenCV code (the code is implemented in C++).

---

The exception message looks like gibberish but looking carefully implies the reason:

> (-215:Assertion failed)

Means that the "asserted" (C++) expression is `false`.

> `!_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat())`

The above statement applies a logical **and** between 3 terms.
If one of the three is `false`, the expression is evaluated to `false` (and `false` raises and exception):

- `!_image.empty()` is `false` is image is empty, but we know image is not empty.
- `_image.type() == CV_8UC1` is `false` in case image type is not `CV_8UC1`.
- `(_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat())` is not going to be `false` when executing from Python (ignore it).

We may conclude that `_image.type() == CV_8UC1` is `false`.

---

What is the meaning of `CV_8UC1`?

The OpenCV images types has a naming convention.

- `8U` applies 8 bits per component (each element is `uint8` type).
- `C1` applies `1` color channel.

For colored image in BGR color format, the type is `CV_8UC3` (`C3` applies `3` color channels).

You can verify that the type of `img` is a `uint8` NumPy array.
Verify that `img.dtype` is `dtype('uint8')` (it probably is)...

You may check the number of color channels, by inspecting `img.shape`.
You are going to see that `img.shape` is `(cols, rows, 3)` (`3` applies 3 color channels).
For Grayscale images (one color channel) we need the shape to be `(cols, rows)`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll go home and check on my ball. Also, is this the best way of detecting a ping pong ball.

Comment: My answer involves the error message (only the error message). I don't know if your code is correct. I don't know if the code is going to detect a ping pong ball. I can't execute the code, because I don't have the video. It's probably not the "best way". No one can tell what is the "best way"...

Comment: Thanks for that, but would this be suitable for a fluorescent ball on a black background, there can't be too much right?